# Rig_ui.py script file disabled for SECURITY reasons. Should I worry about this?

Tags: error

[image]

I am getting this error when I open the .blend file, both in Linux (Pop OS 19.10) and Windows 10.
I can't help but wonder if this has something to do with the "strange behavior" I am experiencing with a file: All the 3 elements of a Physics object disappeared, but the particles are still being emitted. Problem is, I can't modify it anymore.

I did a search for this file in the Add-ons list and not even Rigify has this file. Also nothing came up when searching the C: drive.

I wonder if anyone else has seen this error.

Comment: The warning appears because running scrips is potentially a risk, but you can choose Allow Execution if you trust the sources. To minimize errors you can enable the execution of scripts permanently.

Comment: It's mentioned in the official documentation here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/basics.html ... so presumably it's a legitimate script.

Comment: how do I do that?
i´m don´t understand.