# Link a rig have an issue with character IK FK setting v3.5

Tags: animation, rigging

[image]

The character link is: https://studio.blender.org/characters/sprite/v1/

I followed the instructions to link the character to my scene.
1: Put your 3D cursor in the Origin of your scene. Choose File > Link and browse the character file
2: Go to the Collections and select CH-sprite. Make sure "Instance Collections" is enabled. Press Enter.
3: The Collection should appear instanced in the Viewport. Select it.
4: Choose Object > Library Override > Make.

Q1:
on the Sidebar (press N), there have no Setting bar for the rig; I can't change the switch Ik or FK; how can I load the rig bar here so I can switch the IK or FK

Q2:
on the Scene Collection, there are icons(link icon with a right down arrow) that I don't understand. Is this a problem I need to fix?

I searched a lot of videos, on old Blender using a proxy; once they link and proxy a rig, they have a rig setting on the Sidebar, and they can change the setting of the rig; also, on their Scene Collection, they don't have the icons which I have.

I am new to Blender and used Maya for character animation.

If I open the rig blend file, I can see a rig setting Sidebar.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy system was replaced by the new Library override system in Blender 3. The icons in the outliner indicate that the collections are linked from another file.

To see the rig's custom switches and buttons, there is still one step missing. You need to run some scripts.

[CloudRig](https://studio.blender.org/training/pipeline-and-tools/cloudrig/) is a feature-set (extension) of the Rigify add-on that is included to Blender. The custom controls in the side panel of 3D viewport (<kbd>N</kbd>) are created by a script called "cloudrig.py". (For Rigify rigs it's called "rig_ui.py".)

This script is usually executed automatically when you open the Blend file and you have to confirm a security warning, as you can see here. The warning is shown once after Blender is started.

[image: rigify script security warning]

(taken from the question [Rig_ui.py script file disabled for SECURITY reasons. Should I worry about this?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/175458/107598))

**Long story short:** Save the blend file and open it again. Then allow the script to run.

There is another custom script by Blender Studio included ("sprite_rename_curves.py") that will executed, too.

You can check the scripts in the *Scripting* workspace. Just select the script from the dropdown list that is located at the top of the text editor, right next to the menu.

Comment: Thank you sooooo Much,save my life!